# Program to interface - but with custom methods on implementation

Tags: java

I recently experienced this problem with an implementation of a class in Spring Boot that I couldn't program to its interface because the methods I'm trying to call on the implementation don't exist on the interface.

I'll simplify the problem; below are an interface and an implementation of that interface:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public String beep();
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    public String beep() {
        return "BEEP!";
    }

    public String breakDown() {
        return "CRASH BANG WALLOP";
    }
}
```

If I reference the car as a vehicle, I can't use the `breakDown` method as it doesn't exist on the interface;

```
public void test() {
    Vehicle myVehicle = new Car();
    myVehicle.breakDown();
}
```

Is there a way around this?

For reference, the Spring Boot implementation I was having problems with is the `JavaMailSenderImp` class which implements the `JavaMailServer` interface, but I also have custom methods which I can't access when I program to its interface.

Comment: The idea is to design to the interface.  If the interface doesn't contain the methods you want to use, then you don't want to inject an object that is referenced *just* by the interface.

Comment: So if the interface is one in another package, then I'm better off creating a new interface that extends the original interface and that has the new method signatures in it. Then program to my new interface instead?

Comment: Honestly, that's probably a cleaner implementation than merely casting, since it's implied that you're trying to do this through Spring.  Want me to codify this as an answer?

Comment: @SheppardDigital The package where it's located shouldn't really have anything to do with how you design your solution...but yes, you should try to program to the interface, rather than to the class implementing that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always cast the object into specific type and use the custom methods

```
((Car) myVehicle).breakDown();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the type of the class implementing the interface you can simply cast to that type:

```
public void test() {
    Vehicle myVehicle = new Car();
    ((Car) myVehicle).breakDown();
}
```

Depending on your code, this may cause a warning about an unchecked cast, which you can either suppress directly using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, or by using `instanceof` to verify the type before casting.

Ultimately, though, this points at a problem in your code design; the purpose of interfaces is to abstract the implementation details away from the code using your service, and reduce coupling. If you're coding to an interface, ideally you should be able to swap out implementations in the background without any impact to code interacting with your service.

Comment: Yes, the problem above is within my code, but my original problem exists with the JavaMailServerImp class in org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl, it implements an interface but then also provides custom methods.

Comment: @SheppardDigital Which of those methods are you specifically trying to use directly? At a glance those are intended to be internal-only methods, supporting the interface's `createMimeMessage` and `send` methods...

Comment: I was following step 3.1 in this article http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email as I have a project that needs to use multiple SMTP accounts. I had wanted to use Springs default configuration and provide an alternative SMTP, but struggled because the implementation in the article above can't be programmed to it's interface.

Comment: @SheppardDigital In step 3.1 you're creating the instance, so you need to use the Impl class there. (That's similar to the `new Car()` line in your example, but the construction of the instance is more complicated). Once you have the instance configured as a spring bean, you use the interface after that (by autowiring it in wherever you need it).